# WPA2 authentication fails using USB network devices (Linksys and Rosewill)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, wpa2

Decided to reduce the clutter in the house and replace a wired connection with a wireless one on my wife's system using USB network device Rosewill RNX-X1.  I can see and connect to unprotected network, but WPA2 authentication repeatedly fails.  Tried the same with a Linksys USB network adapter.  Both failed to authenticate.

Worth noting that I recently switched from Comcast to CenturyLink and so switched routers. The system connected successfully to previous router (Linksys EA4500) using WPA2.  Would think it is the router (Actiontec C1000A) but all other devices (TV, iPad, Windows, Blackberry, and Squeezebox) connect ok.

Would appreciate some diagnostic guidance and insight.  The following is the result of the analysis script suggested in the thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10564143&postcount=7

---

pci wireless devices

---

---

usb wireless devices

---

```
    Bus 001 Device 010: ID 148f:2870 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870 Wireless Adapter
```

---

List of network devices

---

```
      *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 01
   serial: 00:e0:4d:30:40:a1
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:47 ioport:ac00(size=256) memory:fdcff000-fdcfffff memory:fdb00000-fdb1ffff
      *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@1:2
   logical name: wlan1
   serial: 00:02:6f:bd:30:a0
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=3.2.0-31-generic firmware=0.29 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

---

List of drivers

---

```
    Module                  Size  Used by
    rndis_wlan             28472  0 
    rndis_host             13560  1 rndis_wlan
    cdc_ether              13312  1 rndis_host
    usbnet                 25214  3 rndis_wlan,rndis_host,cdc_ether
    bnep                   17830  2 
    parport_pc             32114  0 
    rfcomm                 38139  0 
    bluetooth             158438  10 bnep,rfcomm
    ppdev                  12849  0 
    vesafb                 13516  1 
    binfmt_misc            17292  1 
    snd_hda_codec_hdmi     31775  1 
    snd_hda_codec_realtek   174313  1 
    nvidia              10962290  30 
    snd_usb_audio         101566  1 
    snd_usbmidi_lib        24603  1 snd_usb_audio
    arc4                   12473  2 
    snd_hda_intel          32765  3 
    snd_hda_codec         109562  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
    snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
    snd_rawmidi            25424  2 snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_midi
    uvcvideo               67203  0 
    videodev               86588  1 uvcvideo
    snd_hwdep              13276  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
    snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
    rt2800usb              22300  0 
    rt2800lib              53264  1 rt2800usb
    crc_ccitt              12595  1 rt2800lib
    rt2x00usb              20061  1 rt2800usb
    rt2x00lib              48805  3 rt2800usb,rt2800lib,rt2x00usb
    mac80211              436455  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00usb,rt2x00lib
    cfg80211              178679  3 rndis_wlan,rt2x00lib,mac80211
    snd_pcm                80845  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
    snd_seq                51567  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
    psmouse                96619  0 
    serio_raw              13027  0 
    i2c_nforce2            12906  0 
    k8temp                 12905  0 
    snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
    snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
    snd_page_alloc         14115  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
    snd                    62064  20                                   snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_rawmidi,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
    soundcore              14635  1 snd
    wmi                    18744  0 
    mac_hid                13077  0 
    lp                     17455  0 
    parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
    usbhid                 41906  0 
    hid                    77367  1 usbhid
    r8169                  56321  0 
    pata_amd               13750  0
```

---

network info

---

```
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:4d:30:40:a1  
      inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:4dff:fe30:40a1/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:174441 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:125781 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:147560093 (147.5 MB)  TX bytes:20180051 (20.1 MB)
      Interrupt:47 Base address:0x8000 

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:14810 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:14810 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1474361 (1.4 MB)  TX bytes:1474361 (1.4 MB)

    wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:02:6f:bd:30:a0  
      inet6 addr: fe80::202:6fff:febd:30a0/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:148 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:148 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:19980 (19.9 KB)  TX bytes:22940 (22.9 KB)
```

---

Wireless specific network info

---

```
    lo        no wireless extensions.

    eth0      no wireless extensions.

    wlan1     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Youtz Family"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 20:76:00:86:7D:84   
      Bit Rate:6.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:6  Invalid misc:2   Missed beacon:0

    Wed Oct  3 17:51:32 CDT 2012
```

Would appreciate insight on how to chase this down.